# Condition on multiple values in the same column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, algorithm, conditional-statements

Firstly, thanks in advance for helping. This will be my first question on SOF.

I have the following SQL database tables.

`qualificationTable`:

```
QualId  studentNo   CourseName   Percentage

1       1           A            91 
2       1           B            81
3       1           C            71
4       1           D            61
5       2           A            91
6       2           B            81
7       2           C            71
8       2           D            59
```

`testTable`:

```
TestId  studentNo   testNo  Percentage dateTaken

1       1           1       91         2016-05-02
2       1           2       41         2015-05-02
3       1           3       71         2016-04-02
4       1           1       95         2014-05-02
5       1           2       83         2016-01-02
6       1           3       28         2015-05-02
7       2           1       90         2016-05-02
8       2           2       99         2016-05-02
9       2           3       87         2016-05-02
```

I have the minimum percentages specified for courses A, B, C and D individually. I need to search for students, meeting the minimum criteria for ALL the courses.

Part-2:
That student should also match the criteria (minimum percentages specified individually for the three tests- 1,2 and 3) in testTable.

In other words, if a student matches the minimum criteria (percentage) specified individually for all the courses, he should be selected. Now, same goes for the testTable, that particular student (who got selected in qualificationTable) should have the minimum criteria (percentage) specified individually for the three tests (1,2 and 3) in  testNo column.

**Edit:**

I have updated the testTable, now there are multiple tests for a particular student. I need to check if the student meets the minimum required percentage specified for all the 3 tests, however, only the most recently taken test in each no (1,2 and 3) should count. If the student does not meet the minimum criteria specified for the most recent test, he should not be included.

**Test Case:**

Minimum qualification percentage required:

> Course A: 90 Course B: 80 Course C: 70 Course D: 60

Minimum tests percentage required:

> Test 1: 90 Test 2: 80 Test 3: 70

**Expected Output**

```
studentNo

1
```

Cheers

Comment: `count(distinct CourseName)`?

Comment: can you post your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just figured it out for your sample data and **Test Case**:

> Minimum qualification percentage required:
>
> > Course A: 90 Course B: 80 Course C: 70 Course D: 60
>
> Minimum tests percentage required:
>
> > Test 1: 90 Test 2: 80 Test 3: 70

Try this, may help for you;)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5bcc3/4)

**MySQL Schema**:

```
CREATE TABLE qualificationTable
    (`QualId` int, `studentNo` int, `CourseName` varchar(1), `Percentage` int)
;

INSERT INTO qualificationTable
    (`QualId`, `studentNo`, `CourseName`, `Percentage`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'A', 91),
    (2, 1, 'B', 81),
    (3, 1, 'C', 71),
    (4, 1, 'D', 61),
    (5, 2, 'A', 91),
    (6, 2, 'B', 81),
    (7, 2, 'C', 71),
    (8, 2, 'D', 50)
;


CREATE TABLE testTable
    (`TestId` int, `studentNo` int, `testNo` int, `Percentage` int)
;

INSERT INTO testTable
    (`TestId`, `studentNo`, `testNo`, `Percentage`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 91),
    (2, 1, 2, 81),
    (3, 1, 3, 71),
    (4, 2, 1, 80),
    (5, 2, 2, 99),
    (6, 2, 3, 87)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select t1.studentNo
from 
(
  select studentNo from qualificationTable
  where (CourseName = 'A' and Percentage >= 90)
  or (CourseName = 'B' and Percentage >= 80)
  or (CourseName = 'C' and Percentage >= 70)
  or (CourseName = 'D' and Percentage >= 60)
  group by studentNo
  having count(1) = 4
) t1 join
( select studentNo from testTable
  where (testNo = '1' and Percentage >= 90)
  or (testNo = '2' and Percentage >= 80)
  or (testNo = '3' and Percentage >= 70)
  group by studentNo
  having count(1) = 3
) t2 on t1.studentNo = t2.studentNo
```

I just pick `t1` one of these two subquery to explain how it works:

- [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html) can get us a result like this,

```
    | studentNo |
    |-----------|
    |         1 |
    |         2 |
```

- [`COUNT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html) will get us total count of each group, for your sample data, studentNo(1) is 4, studentNo(2) is 4 as well, but we also has where clause here, so by these criteria, we can find which matched are following record,

```
    (1, 1, 'A', 91),
    (2, 1, 'B', 81),
    (3, 1, 'C', 71),
    (4, 1, 'D', 61),
    (5, 2, 'A', 91),
    (6, 2, 'B', 81),
    (7, 2, 'C', 71)
```

- And this means `COUNT` will give us studentNo(1) to 4, studentNo(2) to 3, so when mysql run `having count(1) = 4`, this subquery only return us studentNo(1)

Subquery `t2` works like that, and when join these two subquery by studentNo, it will return what you expected result.

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5bcc3/4/0)**:

```
| studentNo |
|-----------|
|         1 |
```

***Edited:***

```
select t1.studentNo
from 
(
  select studentNo from qualificationTable
  where (CourseName = 'A' and Percentage >= 90)
  or (CourseName = 'B' and Percentage >= 80)
  or (CourseName = 'C' and Percentage >= 70)
  or (CourseName = 'D' and Percentage >= 60)
  group by studentNo
  having count(1) = 4
) t1 join
( select studentNo
  from (
      select *
      from testTable
      where (testNo, dateTaken) in (
          select testNo, Max(dateTaken) from testTable group by testNo
      )
  ) tmp
  where (testNo = '1' and Percentage >= 90)
  or (testNo = '2' and Percentage >= 80)
  or (testNo = '3' and Percentage >= 70)
  group by studentNo
  having count(1) = 3
) t2 on t1.studentNo = t2.studentNo
```

Comment: Works like a charm :D Could you please quickly explain how GROUP BY and HAVING works (in this context)? I'm new to SQL and find online explanations to be complex. :/

Comment: @Singhal2 sure, I've update my post, check again pls.

Comment: Awesome, so COUNT basically returns the number of conditions that particular student has met in the WHERE clause? and if that number is equal to 4, that student is selected? Sweet :D

Comment: I have updated the requirements, could you please take a look. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Singhal2 Now you've just edited `testTable`, and if your sample data is just that, I don't think there are any student to match the minimum criteria, think about this `7       2           1       80         2016-05-02` record in `testTable`.

Comment: @Singhal2 By this requirements, I've updated my post, check it pls.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I have updated the same. Also, the query doesn't seem to be working. 

`Unknown column t1.studentNo in ''field list`

Answer (score 0):

```
First find students who does not qualify the minimum percentage.

select distinct studentNo
from stdqualificationmaster
where case when CourseName='A' and  Percentage<90 then 'F' 
           when CourseName='B' and  Percentage<80 then 'F'
           when CourseName='C' and  Percentage<70 then 'F'
           when CourseName='D' and  Percentage<60 then 'F'
      end='F'

As a second step we can use above unqualified students result set as filter for required result set.

select * from stdqualificationmaster where studentNo not in 
(    select distinct studentNo
from stdqualificationmaster
where case when CourseName='A' and  Percentage<90 then 'F' 
           when CourseName='B' and  Percentage<80 then 'F'
           when CourseName='C' and  Percentage<70 then 'F'
           when CourseName='D' and  Percentage<60 then 'F'
      end='F')
```

Comment: Interesting, let's say we have 1 out of 100,000 students matching the criteria, this will make us go through all 99,999 students who don't first in order to find the one who does. +1 for the approach :)

Comment: if you have knowledge share it and you are sharing it...you don't have to mix your attitude to that +100 for you superb attitude :))))

Comment: I apologise if I came across as a bit cocky. Meant no offence :/